# How can I keep the user's last stage when the user's navigate to other's page and come back?

Tags: html

Hi I have html pages and jsp page

```
<div id="body">
        <div id="header">
            <div>
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="../Html/index.html"></a>
                </div>
                <ul id="navigation">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/Project/Html/features.html">Features</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/Project/Html/news.html">News</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/Project/Html/about.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/Project/Html/contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                  <!--  <li class="active">
                        <a href="../JSF/Login.xhtml">Login</a>
                    </li> --> 
                </ul>
            </div>

    </div>
```

I have no idea how can I  do when the user logged in and went back to features.html or other pages and coming back to the page the user's had logged in I want to show the last stage that user is in.Please help me.How can I do that? 
        Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you need to show?

Comment: javascript cookies (see jQuery cookies also)\

Comment: Hi Brad, I need to show the user's logged in page. if the user's has entered some data also I need to show all.Regards